# String handling in PHP

Tags: php, string

Can anyone please explain me how string handling is done in PHP. Is it the same as that of done with Java or any other way round. Is there anything like java's StringBuffer class in PHP which will improve the performance of my code while handlling strings.

Please shed light on this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "string handling"?

Comment: I would assume he is asking how PHP handles the string internally on the c level.

Comment: Look here for a list of PHP's string functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: @MitMaro: Yes. I wanted to know about that only...just like in java we have string an object is php also consider it as an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are mutable in php. The only reason something like a `StringBuilder` is necessary in Java is because `String`s are immutable. You can use the concatenation operator (`.`) all you want.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are handled in PHP without much fuss or need for additional libraries (unless you want to start using stuff like UTF-8 encoding).

Native PHP strings are mutable just like the StringBuffer class.

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) is a good place to start.

Comment: You linked the string functions. The chapter about strings themselves may be found here: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Well you can read all about strings in the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php),  that might answer some of your queries.

Answer (score -1):

What sorts of issues are you expecting exactly? PHP is much more light-weight than Java and you shouldn't expect any performance problems.

For your reference, you can read up on strings in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php